# MS Word vba in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm trying to use ms Access to open up ms word, create formfield and tables but always end up empty. I tried using the same code but replacing the entire code between "with doc" to .formfields("TxtDate").result = me.txt2 and is able to transfer whatever i typed in txt2 into the formfield located in ms word. Thus I'm unsure which portion of the code went wrong. Would like to seek help on my code. Thanks

```
Function FillWordForm()
Dim appword as Word.Application
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim Path as String

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear
Path = "H:\project delta\test.docx"
Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 then
    Set appword = New Word.Application
    appword.Visible = true
End if
Set doc = appword.Documents.open(Path, , False)
With Doc
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:= _
        WdFieldFormTextInput
    ActiveDocument.FormFields.Shaded = Not ActiveDocument.FormFields.Shaded
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=13, NumColumns:= _
        4, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = True
        .Cell(1,1).Select
        Selection.TypeText Text:="S/N"
        .Cell(1,2).Select
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Package Title"
        .Cell(1,3).Select
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Reference"
        .Cell(1,4).Select
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Month"
    End With
appword.Visible = True
appword.Activate
End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set appword = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your procedure and immediately get compile error "Syntax error" on `Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type= WdFieldFormTextInput`. Need a colon `Type:=`.

Comment: Sorry, phone type all the code, there could be some small mistakes

Comment: Have you step debugged?

Comment: Yes but still no outcome, result still remain blank

Comment: What do you mean by empty/blank? I changed Function to Sub and code runs (after I changed path string). Opens document and adds rows at beginning of table already in document. If I remove table from document, code does not add a table. Do you want to add a table to document?

Comment: I ran the code, no error popped but the ms word does not have the table and all.

Comment: Yes i do wan to add a table and formfields

Comment: I tried re-make everything, it work but the moment i try the second time, it failed, not sure why

Comment: I found out that when i run the code for the first time, it work but when i close ms word and run the code from access it wont work. But when i re open ms access and run the code, it work then i close ms word and run the code, it wont work. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering comments, issue is likely due to a Word process still running in background even though not showing in Task Manager. This can be caused by unqualified references to Word objects.

Prefix `appword.` in front of every `Selection` and `ActiveDocument` usage and code should then run every time. It does for me now.

This can also happen with automation code for other Office apps - Excel, Outlook, PowerPoint, etc.