# MS Access to MS Excel export with VBA coding in MS Excel where having issue

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Below is my code where I'm trying to export a MS Access query output to an Excel file and then editing the Excel to create a pivot table on a new sheet.

The code works fine every alternate time I run the code i.e. on the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th time it is run.

When it is run 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th time it gives an error pointing to the line numbers 74-76 for the TableDestination field where the Activecell is used.

How can I decode the issue with this line?

```
1   Private Sub btnExcelExport_Click()
2       Dim strDesktop As String
3       Dim sFileName As String
4       strDesktop = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"
5       sFileName = strDesktop & "\CRM_Flash_Report.xlsx"
6       DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "FinalReport", acFormatXLSX, sFileName, Autostart:=False
7       Dim xls As Excel.Application
8       Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
9       Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
10      Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
11      Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
12      Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("FinalReport")
13      wks.Name = "Flash_Dump"
14      wks.Cells.WrapText = False
15      wks.Cells.Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS"
16      wks.Cells.Font.Size = "10"
17      Dim MyTableRange As Range
18      Dim TableRange As String
19      wks.Cells(1, 1).Select
20      Set MyTableRange = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
21      TableRange = wks.Name & "!" & MyTableRange.Address
22      wks.Cells(1, 1).Select
23      wkb.Worksheets.Add(Before:=wkb.Worksheets(1)).Name = "Flash_Pivot"
24      Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Flash_Pivot")
25      wks.Cells.Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS"
26      wks.Cells.Font.Size = "10"
27      wkb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
28      TableRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
29      TableDestination:="Flash_Pivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
30      :=xlPivotTableVersion15
31      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Service Line").Orientation = xlRowField
32      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Service Line").Position = 1
33      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").ClearAllFilters
34      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter") _
35      .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=FYShort(DateValue(reportDate))
36      If Not ([Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Mar" Or [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Jun" Or _
37      [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Sep" Or [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Dec") Then
38          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Month").Orientation = xlColumnField
39          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Month").ClearAllFilters
40          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter"). _
41          Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
42          False, False)
43      End If
44      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField wks.PivotTables( _
45      "PivotTable1").PivotFields("POTENTIALID"), "Count of POTENTIALID", xlCount
46      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").Orientation = xlColumnField
47      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").Position = 1
48      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Service Line").AutoSort xlDescending, "Count of POTENTIALID"
49      wks.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(5, 0).Select
50      wkb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
51      TableRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
52      TableDestination:=wks.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
53      TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
54      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("BDO Pursuit Location").Orientation = xlRowField
55      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("BDO Pursuit Location").Position = 1
56      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").ClearAllFilters
57      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter") _
58      .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=FYShort(DateValue(reportDate))
59      If Not ([Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Mar" Or [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Jun" Or _
60      [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Sep" Or [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Dec") Then
61          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Month").Orientation = xlColumnField
62          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Month").ClearAllFilters
63          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter"). _
64          Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
65          False, False)
66      End If
67      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField wks.PivotTables( _
68      "PivotTable2").PivotFields("POTENTIALID"), "Count of POTENTIALID", xlCount
69      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").Orientation = xlColumnField
70      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").Position = 1
71      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("BDO Pursuit Location").AutoSort xlDescending, "Count of POTENTIALID"
72      Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(5, 0).Select
73      wkb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
74      TableRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
75      TableDestination:=wks.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
76      TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
77      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("BDO Pursuit Location").Orientation = xlRowField
78      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("BDO Pursuit Location").Position = 1
79      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").ClearAllFilters
80      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter") _
81      .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=FYShort(DateValue(reportDate))
82      If Not ([Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Mar" Or [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Jun" Or _
83      [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Sep" Or [Forms]![Report]![Combo3] = "Dec") Then
84          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Month").Orientation = xlColumnField
85          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Month").ClearAllFilters
86          wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter"). _
87          Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
88          False, False)
89      End If
90      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField wks.PivotTables( _
91      "PivotTable2").PivotFields("POTENTIALID"), "Count of POTENTIALID", xlCount
92      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").Orientation = xlColumnField
93      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Create_Period_Quarter").Position = 1
94      wks.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("BDO Pursuit Location").AutoSort xlDescending, "Count of POTENTIALID"
95      Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(5, 0).Select
96      wks.Cells(1, 1).Select
97      wkb.Save
98      wkb.Close True
99      Set wks = Nothing
100     Set wkb = Nothing
101     xls.Quit
102     Set xls = Nothing
103     MsgBox "Excel Formatting operation completed"
104 End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact error message you get. You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Remove lines 72 and 95.

Comment: I need the lines between 72 - 95 for creating a second pivot after the first pivot. For the 2nd pivot I find the 5th blank row after the first pivot. And the error that I get on the mentioned lines is - Run-Time error '91': Object Variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Suggestion was to remove two lines (not everything between). Those two lines have unqualified references to Range objects. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013512/ms-word-vba-in-ms-access/71015517#71015517. It is not necessary to Select cells.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the solution to this problem by some trial & error method. The issue was resoled when I replaced the `ActiveCell.`with `xls.` and ran the code multiple times which fortunately worked.

Every time I ran the code earlier, the excel instance was not being closed due to the `ActiveCell.`reference. But when I used `xls.`the excel instance in the memory was properly getting closed by the code at the end of the subroutine.

Thank you for all the people who gave me a direction to think on this issue.